# Is it possible using the PHP5 imagick wrapper?

Tags: imagick

I don't have possibility to run `convert` via cmdline and the only way to use **Imagick** is via the PHP5 wrapper. I would need to run following command:

```
convert in.jpg -channel RGB -auto-level +level-colors red,white out.jpg
```

Unfortunately I haven't found in documentation any method that would perform any of these options. Can somebody with better knowledge of the php wrapper help?

I found only `Imagick::levelImage()` but couldn't simulate `-auto-level` and `level-colors` is nowhere to be found.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got help on imagemagick forum, so for anybody with similar problem, here is what worked for me.

```
$img = new Imagick('in.jpg');
// grayscale image
$img->modulateImage(100, 0, 100);
// instead of auto-level option, where 65535 = Imagick::getQuantumRange()
$img->contrastStretchImage (0, 65535, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALL);

// instead of missing level-colors option, apply clut with the 2 desired colors
$clut = new Imagick();
$clut->newPseudoImage(1, 2, "gradient:red-white");
$img->clutImage($clut);

$img->writeImage('out.jpg');
```

For more info you can read the imagemagick [thread](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=25392&sid=a0e0a9a47c66596c4b2190f13494769e)